# How to Use TabLayout & Spinner Together for Fast Scrolling Between Fragments

Tags: android-spinner, android-tablayout

I'm using TabLayout  for swiping between many fragments in an activity.
I created a Spinner for fast access between these fragments that user can access each items he wants. 
But I don't know how to sync TabLayout info with Spinner items, and how to get each tab's item's number to set it for each spinner items, and how this access works.
I'm using FragmentPagerAdapter and TabLayout works fine.

Comment: Nobody can answer me? Or there is no way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 1 week, I found my answer.
I just used `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);` in Spinner `onItemSelected`.
it works for me. when I select one of this items, fragments will change.